# Adding Special Folders in Header for Acumation Versions 2021 R2 and Above

Tags: c#, user-interface, button, header, acumatica

I'm trying to add a drop down button in the header similar to the image provided(https://i.stack.imgur.com/57YOr.png).

I'm trying to use these codes that I had been using before the version 2021 R2.

```
public override void Initialize()
        {
            base.Initialize();
            customActivityFolder.AddMenuAction(ChatCustom);
        }

public PXAction<SOOrder> customActivityFolder;
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Activity2333", MapEnableRights = PXCacheRights.Select, Visibility = PXUIVisibility.Visible, Visible = true)]
[PXButton(CommitChanges = true, SpecialType = PXSpecialButtonType.ToolbarFolder)]
protected virtual void CustomActivityFolder()
{
}
  
public PXAction<SOOrder> ChatCustom;
[PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Chat")]
protected IEnumerable chatCustom(PXAdapter adapter)
{
    return Base.Actions["NewActivityC"].Press(adapter);         
}
```

Is it still possible to add folders/dropdown buttons in the header without reverting back to the old toolbar(QPToolbar)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if its still supported, but I suspect not, and I assume it will eventually be deprecated. Take this wonderful opportunity to learn how to move your action definitions into the new workflow method :) :

```
public override void Configure(PXScreenConfiguration graph)
    {
        graph.GetScreenConfigurationContext<YourGraph, MainDAC>()
            .AddScreenConfigurationFor(screenConfig =>
            {
                screenConfig
                    .WithActions(actions =>
                    {
                        actions.Add(a => a.YourAction,
                            config => config
                                .InFolder(FolderType.ActionsFolder));
                    });

                
                return screenConfig;
            });

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it did not work. I just moved to using smart panels as a workaround for now. thank you again.